# Prevent custom ToolPanel from collapsing on render

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a simple custom ToolPanel registered with my AgGrid. It's a functional react component that is updated whenever the selected rows change. Unfortunately, I'm finding that whenever my component needs to re-render (such as when the selection changes) the tool panel collapses?!

This is very annoying - I would like the ToolPanel to remain open across re-renders. Please advise!

Here's more or less what my ToolPanel code looks like:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
`;

export interface MyToolPanelProps {
  selected: MyRowData[];
}

export const MyToolPanel = (props: MeToolPanelProps) => {

  return (params: IToolPanelParams) => {
      return (
      <Container>
        <AnotherComponentThatProcessesSelectedItems
          {...props} 
        />
      </Container>
    );
  };
};
```

Here's how I'm injecting it into AgGrid:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<MyRowData[]>([]);

...

gridOptions.onSelectionChanged = (e) => 
    setSelected(e.api.getSelectedRows());

...

<AgGridReact
   gridOptions={gridOptions}
   sideBar={{ 
       toolPanels: ["columns", "filters", 
       {
         id: 'myToolPanel',
         labelDefault: 'My Tool Panel',
         labelKey: 'myToolPanel',
         iconKey: 'columns',
         toolPanel: MyToolPanel({
             selected: selected
         }),
      }]
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the documentation on the website closer, I found that I was able to achieve what I wanted by making my functional component use the api to subscribe to the selectionChanged event. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-tool-panel/

```
const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
`;

export const MyToolPanel = (props: IToolPanelParams) => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<MyRowData[]>(props.api.getSelectedRows());

  const onSelectionChanged = (e: SelectionChangedEvent) => {
    setSelected(e.api.getSelectedRows());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    props.api.addEventListener('selectionChanged', onSelectionChanged);

    return () => {
      props.api.removeEventListener('selectionChanged', onSelectionChanged);
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container>
      <AnotherComponentThatProcessesSelectedItems
        selected={selected}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Works like a charm now :)